# Powers of two array(n)

Tags: java, arrays

My code isn't working

```
public static int[] powersOfTwoArray(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n];
    int i = 0;
    int power = 0;
    while (i <= n) {
        result[i] = power;
        power *= 2;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The method should return an array containing the powers of 2 from 2
raise to 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are **three** problems with your code, I have mentioned them in the code:

```
public static int[] powersOfTwoArray(int n) 
{
    int[] result = new int[n+1];  // use "n+1" otherwise it will throw exception
    int i = 0;
    int power = 1;   // initiate power = 1, not power = 0;
    while (i <= n) 
    {
        result[i] = power;
        power *= 2;
        i++;        // increments "i" otherwise its an infinite loop
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!This was very helpful!

Comment: Next time first dry run each line of code... and you'l debug the code by yourself

Comment: Thanks,I'll do that next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing multiplication with zero, which everytime equals zero.
Try

```java
int power = 1;
```

Please specify your question if I misunderstood it.

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake